# How to check [sp,#4] value in gdb

Tags: c, assembly, arm, gdb

I'm new to C. I'm trying to debug my code in GDB, with assembly lanugage.

In assembly there is "ldr r0, [sp, #4]". How can I check sp+4 's value? not address.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't as convenient as you'd probably like it to be, because there aren't any built-in $variables for most of the registers.  There *may* be a $variable for the stack pointer, though.

First use `info register sp` to get the value of sp.  (Replace `sp` with whichever register you're interested in.  `info register` all by itself will print all of the registers' values.)

Then use the `x` command to inspect memory at sp+4.  You'll have to copy and paste the value of sp into the command.  `x` takes a variety of suffixes to specify how much memory to read and how to format it, see `help x` for details.

For example:

```
(gdb) info register sp
sp            0x7fffdcd8          -9000
(gdb) x/xw 0x7fffdcd8 + 4
0x7fffdcdc: 0x00005555
```

If there *is* a $variable for the stack pointer, its name will be `$sp`, and you can simplify this to

```
(gdb) x/xw $sp + 4
0x7fffdcdc: 0x00005555
```

Unfortunately I don't know any way to list all the built-in $variables.  On my computer `show conv` only shows the built-in $variables that *aren't* registers.

Comment: I thought GDB for most targets let you use `$reg_name` for any register.  And `$pc` for the program counter, whatever it's called on the target (e.g. RIP on x86-64).